# How to remove remaining space in ffmpeg thumbnails

Tags: ffmpeg

I have searched in many ways to solve this problem. But I can't find an answer, so I leave a question.

```
ffmpeg -i thumb_test.mp4 -filter_complex "select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,5)',scale=120:-1,tile=layout=60x60" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb.jpg
```

The result of the command I used is as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy5on.png)

I want remove remaining black space.
Please let me know if there is a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Get duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/110524).
2. Divide duration by your `select` interval (which is `5` in your example).
3. Use the result to determine an appropriate `layout`.

Example: Duration is 120 seconds. 120/5=24. Use `tile=layout=6x4`.

Comment: Is it possible to extract to fit the length of the video from the beginning?

Comment: @JeeNi I don't understand your question.